# How do I retrieve these value from a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to access a nested element from a JSON file. To be more specific i'm getting information from a RSS feed and converting to JSON with an api and retrieving that information with JQuery using the $.each method. The element that i'm trying to retrieve is "link", but the following line does not work. I'm just only able to output the title object. How do i fix this?

Thanks!

Here's my JQuery code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Js Test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $(function () {
            var $content = $('#roundupContent');
            var data = {
                rss_url: 'http://roundup.calpolycorporation.org/~api/papers/b686f300-0de4-458f-9b51-07756c12d705/rss'
            };
            $.get('https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json', data, function (response) {
                if (response.status == 'ok') {
                    var output = '';
                    $.each(response.items, function (k, item) {
                        //I can output the title
                        var title = item.title;
                        console.log(title);

                        //But i cant output the image link
                        var tagIndex = item.enclosure.link;
                        console.log(tagIndex);
                        return k < 1;
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is part of the JSON code:

```
    {
"items": [
    {
        "title": "Mustangs in Pros: Marinconz, Meyer Hitting Well in Start to Pro Career",
        "pubDate": "2018-07-11 04:00:00",
        "link": "https://www.gopoly.com/sports/bsb/2017-18/releases/20180711m0l4q1",
        "guid": "b385bac9-6997-4bd8-b6d6-71c4ab011fdf",
        "author": "",
        "thumbnail": "",
        "description": "<p><strong>gopoly.com</strong> - SAN LUIS OBISPO, Calif. — The top hitters for former Cal Poly position players in professional baseball are Mitch Haniger of the Seattle Mariners, Kyle Marinconz of the Auburn Doubledays, Nick Meyer …</p>",
        "content": "<p><strong>gopoly.com</strong> - SAN LUIS OBISPO, Calif. — The top hitters for former Cal Poly position players in professional baseball are Mitch Haniger of the Seattle Mariners, Kyle Marinconz of the Auburn Doubledays, Nick Meyer …</p>",
        "enclosure": {
            "link": "http://www.gopoly.com/sports/bsb/2017-18/Marinconz-MeyerMinors.jpg?max_width=600&amp;max_height=600"
        },
        "categories": [
            "Sports"
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Cal Poly's digital transformation hub lets students take technology to government",
        "pubDate": null,
        "link": "https://edscoop.com/california-polytechnic-state-university-digital-transformation-hub-lets-students-take-technology-to-government",
        "guid": "86cec9b0-2be1-4438-90fa-ff1a4564655f",
        "author": "",
        "thumbnail": "",
        "description": "<p><strong>edscoop.com</strong> - Students at California Polytechnic State University (Cal Poly) don’t have to go far to get real-world problem-solving experience with the latest technology. Since last October, Cal Poly students and …</p>",
        "content": "<p><strong>edscoop.com</strong> - Students at California Polytechnic State University (Cal Poly) don’t have to go far to get real-world problem-solving experience with the latest technology. Since last October, Cal Poly students and …</p>",
        "enclosure": {
            "link": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/edscoop-media/uploads/dxhub.jpg?mtime=20180712160104"
        },
        "categories": [
            "Technology"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: That is really weird. If you can log the title successfully, there is no reason why the link is not getting logged. The key you use to access the link seems correct to me. Do you see any error in the console?

Comment: Running that exact code on my computer (latest Chrome / macOS), it appears to print both the title and the image link successfully: https://i.imgur.com/TSfHCWP.png

What do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(function () {
        var $content = $('#roundupContent');
        var data = {
            rss_url: 'http://roundup.calpolycorporation.org/~api/papers/b686f300-0de4-458f-9b51-07756c12d705/rss'
        };
        $.get('https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json', data, function (response) {
            if (response.status == 'ok') {
                var output = '';
                $.each(response.items, function (k, item) {
                    //I can output the title
                    var title = item.title;
                    var tagIndex;
                    // If you want to store link in array
                    var tagIndexes = [];

                    $.each(item.enclosure, function (index, link) {
                        tagIndex = link;
                        tagIndexes.push(link)
                    });
                    console.log(tagIndex);
                    console.log(tagIndexes);
                    return k < 1;
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Error @ my prev answer; try this code:

```
    var $content = $('#roundupContent');
    var data = {
        rss_url: 'http://roundup.calpolycorporation.org/~api/papers/b686f300-0de4-458f-9b51-07756c12d705/rss'
    };
    $.get('https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json', data, function (response) {
    console.log(response);
        if (response.status == 'ok') {
            var output = '';
            $.each(response.items, function (k, item) {
                //I can output the title
                var title = item.title;
                var enclosure = item.enclosure.link;
                console.log(title);
                console.log(enclosure);
                return k < 1;
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is functionally the same code as the OP, just with a different variable name, line ordering, and an extra console log, right?

Comment: Apperantly so, I just dumped it out of my ATOM and seems to have worked fine; I was able to get the image URL in var enclosure where OP attempted var tagIndex = item.enclosure.link; and it did not work; paste the snip in a blank local HTML and open in Chrome you'll see what I mean

Answer (score 1):

```
(
    function () {
    var $content = $('#roundupContent');
    var data = {
      rss_url: 'http://roundup.calpolycorporation.org/~api/papers/b686f300-0de4-458f-9b51-07756c12d705/rss'
    };
    $.getJSON('https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json', data, function (response) {
      if (response.status == 'ok') {
        var output = '';
        $.each(response.items, function (k, item) {

           console.dir(item);
          //I can output the title
          var title = item.title;
          console.log(title);

          //But i cant output the image link
          var tagIndex = item.enclosure.link;
          console.log(tagIndex);
          return k < 1;
        });
      }
    });
  })();
```